# Update related list view

Tags: custom-object, related-list, standard-objects, junction-object

I have a custom object with a master-detail relationship to some standard objects through a junction object. On the related list view on the standard object, I would like to:

1. Remove the checkboxes on the list view and
2. Add the view as an option in addition to Edit and New on the dropdown.

I am not able to find the option to make this work because the object defaults to the standard page for the list view and there is no option to change this.

Please see the attached images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about Related Lists or List Views? Could you please add some more context? It's not entirely clear what UI elements your screenshots are referring to, and whether they're even customizable in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
Try to build a new custom view component in Aura which would give you control on the page ..
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/documentation

or a data table in lwc which is much easier **(RECOMMENDED)**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/8342b2812fa2b8a80aecde269c3530aa91a56694/edit

**Option 2:**

1. To My Knowledge adding an additional button is not possible
2. For the checkboxes:

They render depending on

- If your list view contains more than one record type, the checkboxes will not be rendered.
- If "Enhanced List View" or "Inline editing" are disabled they will not be rendered
- If Profile permission "Mass Edit from Lists" is revoked they will not be rendered to the user